# Why inhbition of RTK will not help in a case of mutant EGF?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane, cell-signaling, receptor

I was given the following as an example for a quiz question but i don't understand the answer. Any help will be most welcome:

> **Question:** Iressa is a Tyrosine Kinase Inhibitor. As a young oncologe, to whome of the patients will you recommand **not** to take this treatment:
>
> a. Biopsia has shown that the EGF receptor is mutant
>
> b. Biopsia has shown that the RAS protein is mutant
>
> c. Biopsia has shown that the MAP Kinase stays in the nucleuous permanently
>
> d. The treatment can help each of a,b,c, cases.

The right answer should be a. Can someone see why and help here?

I know that tyrosine kinase receptor is the inside part of the EGF receptor (where the two monomeres become a dimer and phosphorelate each other).
So, if the EGF receptor is mutant, shuldn't it help inhibiting it's continuation inside the cell and thus prevent to many EGF cascades?

Thanks!

Comment: Have they given more information how the receptor is mutant?

Comment: The right answer should be A? Patients with EGFR-positive lung cancer who are also positive for mutant K-Ras don't respond to erlotinib, a common EGFR-TKI ([example](https://jeccr.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13046-014-0077-6)). This is directly because the bulk of Ras mutations are activating, which would naturally subvert the need for EGFR-RTK signaling to begin with. Thus, for mutant Ras patients I wouldn't recommend TKIs.